# Liferay shows different URL for different machines

Tags: url, liferay, liferay-6

I am seeing different URLs being generated by **Liferay 6.1 GA2** on different machines even when I enter the following same URL in the browser:

```
http://my.ip.0.202:8080/
```

Machine-1's browser generates:

```
http://my.ip.0.202:8080/en_GB/web/guest/home
```

Machine-2's browser generates:

```
http://my.ip.0.202:8080/web/guest/home
```

The configurations on both the machines like language settings, local settings, browser settings, control panel settings seems to be same.

Can anybody tell me the reason for this and how can I force both machine's browser to render the same URL like `http://my.ip.0.202:8080/web/guest/home`

Thanks

Comment: if you call the first machine remote, clear the cache and call the second one remote, do you get the same behavior?

Comment: @MatthiasG I am sorry but I am not able to understand your question since I am a newbie in Liferay, can you explain a little bit more about what you want me to do. Thanks

Comment: You said you have two machines.
If you take a third machine and access them both in the same way, do you get the same results/urls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked the Liferay Wiki: [Configure time zones and locale](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Configure+time+zones+and+locale#section-Configure+time+zones+and+locale-JVM+Locale+and+Time+Zone+Settings).

I have not tried, but according to one of my colleague:

There might be a localization mismatch with the two machines. Therefore, for one machine "en_GB" automatically gets attached to the URL.

The problem can be resolved by setting a property in portal-ext.properties

```
locale.prepend.friendly.url.style=0 (by default it is set to 1).
```

The following is directly from the [`portal.properties`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/portal.properties#L2262):

```
#
# Set this to 0 if the locale is not automatically prepended to a URL. This
# means that each URL could potentially point to many different languages.
# For example, the URL http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home could then be
# viewed by users in many different languages.
#
# Set this to 1 if the locale is automatically prepended to a URL when the
# requested locale is not the default locale. This means that each URL
# points to just one language. For example, the URL
# http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home would point to the default language.
# The URL http://localhost:8080/zh/web/guest/home and
# http://localhost:8080/zh_CN/web/guest/home would both point to the Chinese
# language.
#
# In cases where the prepended locale is "zh" and not complete locale
# "zh_CN", then the full locale returned will be based on the order in which
# the locales appear in the property "locales". If "zh_CN" appears before
# "zh_TW", then "zh" will be a short hand for "zh_TW".
#
# The default language is set in system.properties with the properties
# "user.country" and "user.language".
#
# Set this to 2 if the locale is automatically prepended to every URL. This
# means that each URL points to just one language.
#
# Note that each language requires an entry in the property "locales" and a
# servlet mapping in web.xml for the I18n Servlet.
#
locale.prepend.friendly.url.style=1
```

Hope this helps.